# How to Modify AppSettings key value at run time?

Tags: c#

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["SourceFilePath"].Value = SourcePathTextBox.Text.ToString();
        config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

This is my code to Change key settings value. It is working without error but value Does not change in app setting which is in app.config file.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App.Config` file value will revert back each time you rebuild the solution. This will only work as desired when you deploy your application.

Or You can

Add key to `Settings.settings` like below.

[image]

[image: Settings]

Write to it like this;

```
ModelCodeGenerator.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultTargetPath = txtFolder.Text;
ModelCodeGenerator.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

`ModelCodeGenerator` is my solution name.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given does not persist the changes to your configuration file,t just changes it in memory. You can check the changes using a break point or else you can display the updated values using the following code:.

```
lblConfigChanges.Text=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceFilePath"].ToString();
```